# More than one marker on same place

Tags: javascript, sql, vb.net, google-maps

I want to mark the coordinates in google map  location of each rooms or floor of one building. i am using vb.net, java script and SQL. From the db i will get the locations but all are same latitude and longitude.  when i show this on map i can able to see the last coordinate left all are comes under it.

Comment: Not even close to a full answer, but you could create a custom marker backed by a collection of locations at the same spot.  Overload clicking so that it would show a popup with all locations.

Comment: The Google Maps API has the `Markers` capability, but these marker's position will completely rely on your given coordinates. So if your DB contains the same LatLng data, it will pinpoint to the same location. What you can do is change the LatLng data more precisely by zooming in to the location and precisely choosing a point per room. You can also assign different colors of markers to marker captions to identify which floor is it.